# NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator

Tags: maven, jboss7.x

I am trying to deploy my application war into JBoss EAP 7 server but I am getting below error when deploying. we have esapi jar in our classpath (Jboss-deployment-structure.xml)

```
by: javax.servlet.ServletException: UT010013: Could not instantiate TestClass
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:236)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet.createServlet(ManagedServlet.java:133)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.DeploymentManagerImpl.start(DeploymentManagerImpl.java:527)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService.startContext(UndertowDeploymentService.java:101)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentService$1.run(UndertowDeploymentService.java:82)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: WFLYEE0042: Failed to construct component instance
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:163)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:134)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.createInstance(BasicComponent.java:88)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentRegistry$ComponentManagedReferenceFactory.getReference(ComponentRegistry.java:149)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$6.createInstance(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1372)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet$DefaultInstanceStrategy.start(ManagedServlet.java:234)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ConstructorComponentFactory.create(ConstructorComponentFactory.java:27)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentInstantiatorInterceptor.java:67)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.AroundConstructInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(AroundConstructInterceptorFactory.java:26)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.BasicComponent.constructComponentInstance(BasicComponent.java:161)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ConstructorComponentFactory.create(ConstructorComponentFactory.java:24)
    ... 29 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.owasp.esapi.util.ObjFactory.make(ObjFactory.java:74)
    at org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI.validator(ESAPI.java:191)
    at com.metavante.web.validation.BaseValidator.xssClean(BaseValidator.java:928)
    at com.metavante.web.validation.BaseValidator.sanitizeLogEntry(BaseValidator.java:1025)
    at com.metavante.web.validation.BaseValidator.sanitizeLogEntry(BaseValidator.java:1010)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.logStore.types.Log4jLogStore.store(Log4jLogStore.java:38)
    at com.metavante.efd.util.logging.logStore.LogStore.error(LogStore.java:600)
    at com.util.logging.Logger.error(Logger.java:163)
    at com.ssc.RemoteProxyFac.createProxy(RemoteProxyFac.java:57)
    at com.usertype.TestApp.<clinit>(TestApp.java:49)
    at com.servlet.TestClass.<init>(TestClass.java:30)
    ... 34 more
```

I am trying to deploy the war using Jboss admin console. Please help me in this regard.

One thing is that, we have different shared projects combined with our application. building those shared projects with maven as jars and adding them into main application war file WEB-INF/lib folder. Now I am deploying that war file which contains all other application jars inside its lib directory.

here is the pom.xml file where we mention the esapi jar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
-<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
-<parent>
<groupId>com.myapp.app</groupId>
<artifactId>myapp-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<groupId>com.myapp.app</groupId>
<artifactId>tools</artifactId>
-<dependencies>
-<dependency>
<groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
<artifactId>activation</artifactId>
</dependency>
-<dependency>
<groupId>commons-net</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>log4j</groupId>
<artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>org.owasp.esapi</groupId>
<artifactId>esapi</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
<artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
</dependency>

 -<dependency>
<groupId>nl.captcha</groupId>
<artifactId>SimpleCaptcha</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
<artifactId>recordio</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
<artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun</groupId>
<artifactId>jai_codec</artifactId>
</dependency>
-<dependency>
<groupId>com.sun</groupId>
<artifactId>jai_core</artifactId>
</dependency>     

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.servlet</groupId>
<artifactId>jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
</dependency>

-<dependency>
<groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
<artifactId>recjava</artifactId>
</dependency>



</dependencies>
</project>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you are missing a class on your `CLASSPATH`. That may be caused by various issues, you have to make sure `org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator` is found by the server's `CLASSPATH`. Please provide your Maven pom.xml we may see something wrong here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  We have esapi-2.0.1.jar in jboss-deployment-structure.xml file and i Updated my question with pom.xml file.

Comment: I am not familiar with JBos deployment model, but your class is probably somehow missing from the Classpath. How do you package your war? Are you sure the path in your deployment xml is correct and jar is readable by user running the server?